# onChange event is not working with `vue-select` npm package

Tags: vue.js, events, vue-select

I am working with vue-select@3.1.0.

Btw, when I select another option, how to hook the @change event?

Current codebase like this:

```
<v-select
  v-model="selected"
  :options="['Vue.js','React']"
  @change="handleChange"
></v-select>
```

```
import vSelect from 'vue-select';

export default {
  components: {
    vSelect,
  },
  methods: {
    handleChange() {
      console.log('HELLO');
    }
  },
};
```

Comment: Try using `@input` instead of @change.

Comment: Check this codesandbox. https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-kqlc1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no such event in this library.

[Vue-select Events](https://vue-select.org/api/events.html).

As an alternative use `@input` event.